# Properly retrying or erroring out on a bad connection with Axios calls

Tags: react-native, react-redux, axios

In my mobile app, some of my users often run into the problem that they get an 'undefined' or a screen that just freezes. After much digging, I have narrowed the problem to axios processes that just do not finish and do not fail out accordingly.

To solve this, I have tried changing timeouts or retrying but this doesn't seem to solve the problem in all cases - many dont seem to hit an error path. An example of one piece of code that updates the state:

```
export const loadChallenges = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_CHALLENGES_START' })
        axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 4 });
        axios.get('/challenges/').then(function (response) {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_CHALLENGES_SUCCESS', payload: response.data })
        }).catch(function (error) {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_CHALLENGES_FAILURE', payload: error })
        })
    }
}
```

What am I missing to make this more robust to timeouts, to retry etc?

My defaults in App.js:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL;
axios.defaults.timeout = 1500;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `timeout` as a config option to any axios request in milliseconds:

```
 axios.get('/challenges/', null { timeout: 5000 }).then(function (response) {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_CHALLENGES_SUCCESS', payload: response.data })
        }).catch(function (error) {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_CHALLENGES_FAILURE', payload: error })
        })
```

Once it times out, it will run your catch block.  I'm not sure how you're handling retries, but you could trigger whatever utility or library you appear to be using within your catch.

Hope this helps!